# Node.js mysql обратиться к столбцу

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
var authUser = function (email, password) {
connection.connect();
var query = connection.query("SELECT * FROM users_admin WHERE email='"+email+"' and user_password='"+password+"'", function (error, result) {
    if (error) {
        throw error
    } else {
        setValue(result);
    }
});

connection.end(function (error) {
    if (error) throw error;
});
}

function setValue(value) {
    someVar = value;
    console.log(someVar);
}
```

Результат выводит как нужно:

```
[ RowDataPacket {
id: 1,
user_name: 'qwerty',
user_surname: 'qwerty',
user_password: 'qwerty',
number_phone: 'qwerty',
email: 'qwerty' } ]
```

Как мне обратиться к определенному полю? Если я пишу console.log(someVar['user_name']), пишет undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как пример, можете изучить данный кусок кода:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  MySQL Connect
------------------------------------------------------------------*/

var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : my_host,
    user     : my_user,
    password : my_password,
    database : my_dbname,
    port     : 3306,
});


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  Query
------------------------------------------------------------------*/

var login;

connection.query('SELECT `login` FROM `users` WHERE `id`="1" ', function (error, rows) {

    for(i in rows) {
        login = rows[i].login;
    }

});
```

Comment: Благодарю, в гугле не нашел(